# Javascript classes from WEB API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am currently working on a CMS, and i want to experiment with something which would be very useful if it could work, but it is very shaky & could be a security concern.
Basically, i want to make a WYSIWYG editor (with EditorJS https://editorjs.io).
The CMS has a JSON WEB API which serves all clients (different websites). Frontend solution is Angular 11.2. In EditorJS we can make different tools by implementing an interface for example:

```
class MyBlockTool{
    render(){
      return document.createElement('someelement');
    }
    save(blockContent){
      return { something: blockContent.someproperty };
    }
}
```

The whole goal would be to make these classes not in the Angular app, but in the actual websites PHP MVC framework, make an endpoint on the mvc which returns data about the custom blocks, and retrieve them in the angular app.
So different websites could have their different, unique tools in addition to the basic tools, for example one websites banner block advertising a product or something would have different css, and most importantly different html structure, different inputs etc...

So far, i know i can define these classes on the fly in the constructor of the EditorJS
So my questions is: How i could get a javascript class from a http request in a way that it is actually usable in the angular app?

One possible solution i thought of is to try and get the raw text content of the .js/ts file, return that in the http request and use eval(), but that is the flagship of security vulnerability obviously, and i also tried it and it kinda doesn't work.

Other, actually the first solution what i thought of is passing the class definition itself in JSON, but i tried defining it in a .json file in my IDE, the whole thing turned to that scary-red color so i would guess json is not meant for that at all.

I just can't figure out a good approach, or even just a bad one that would work (possibly because there isn't one and should not even be one lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass html string, css, js, required inputs for each block in JSON http response. Figure out something to make the input elements correctly, mass produce the classes needed as anonymous classes in some class/function, pass them into the config, that's all. I don't know how i had that massive brainfart with `eval()`. If you would ever consider `eval()` as a viable solution, there is a 99.64% chance that the actual solution is just straightforward but you don't think about it for some reason. Don't use `eval()` unless you have a very good reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (sort-of).
I imported TypeScript into the module, transpiled the code, then used eval() on that, and it is working as i wanted to: made class from string -> passed it into the editor -> editor tool working correctly.

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
const myClassInString = "()=> { const myclass = class MyBlockTool { render(){ return document.createElement('input'); } static get toolbox(){ return { title:'Test', icon: 'halo' }; } save(blockContent){ return { 'dik': 'dik' }; } }; return myclass; }";
//This is basically this:
function(){
   const myclass = new class MyBlockTool{
       //typescript stuff
   }
   return myclass;
}

const myTool = eval(ts.transpile(myClassInString))();

//pass it into editorjs, its working!
```

This is obviously very dirty, and testing new blocks while developing them in a basically separate project (WEB API, the actual cms frontend, and the website are all separate). But maybe i can just make a PHP class which makes typescript out of some arguments so the typescript can be converted into a string which can be transpiled by typescript and evaluated by javascript and this is why i would call this a bad solution. I could also just skip the typescript part as in the end, javascript is being used only.